# Fullscreen API stops draggable functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, fullscreen

I use the jQuery fullscreen API. In the fullscreen mode I can't drag the divs anymore and the dropdown-menu isn't working. How is the correct way to bind, append or activate the eventhandlers again?

```
function drag()
{
    $("#info").draggable({ containment: "body"});
    $("#info2").draggable({ containment: "body"});
    $(".circles").draggable({ containment: "body"});
    $(".drag").draggable({ containment: "body"})
}

$(function() 
{
    $('#fsButton').live('click',function(e)
    {
        $('body').fullScreen()
        drag();
    });
});
```

Comment: Aside from your issues, Jquery's live() is deprecated from version 1.7. You'd be best to use either on() or delegate()